# Where is the documentation for sfdx's configuration options?

Tags: salesforcedx

I know I can configure a default username and default Dev Hub, but is there a description anywhere of all the options supported by `sfdx config`? I've found the [CLI Command Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_config_set.htm), which gives examples, but not an exhaustive list of the available options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is comprehensive documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_dev_cli_config_values.htm)

Use the below, for a lot, there are runtime configurations discussed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_dev_cli_config_values.htm)

You can overwrite runtime with the environment variables. These are discussed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_dev_cli_env_variables.htm)